# Pascal's law in non-cylindrical containers

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics

[image]

So this was a question I came about, and I remembered that pressure in a liquid at all points of the same depth would be equal. I tried to explain it intuitively, but came up grasping at straws.

Generally, we'd say this pressure is created by the column of liquid above it. In this case however, the pressures at the 3 points are equal, yet the heights of the water columns above them aren't.

So why exactly are the pressures at the 3 points equal?

Thanks!

Comment: Pressure in a fluid is transmitted in ALL directions. For that reason, pressure at a certain depth is always the same, regardless of the shape of the container.

Comment: @Gert when you say its transmitted, is it transmitted horizontally? Cuz otherwise the pressure above it should be the same as well.

Comment: It's transmitted in all directions, something that's easy to understand intuitively. The pressure depends on the depth because of the height of the water column, so no the pressure isn't equal in the vertical direction.